# Build a matrix of ones and zeros from two columns in R

Tags: r

I'm still new to R and I'm trying to find a better way to build a matrix with dates as rows and tags as columns filled with ones and zeros if the tag applies to that date from a two-column csv file.

I have some code that works now but I'm betting there's a better way than the hack I've put together.

Here's a sample input:

```
# Sample CSV Data
Date,Tag
01/01/2014,tag1
01/01/2014,tag2
01/01/2014,tag3
01/01/2014,tag4
01/01/2014,tag5
01/01/2014,tag6
01/01/2014,tag7
01/02/2014,tag1
01/02/2014,tag3
01/02/2014,tag4
01/02/2014,tag5
01/02/2014,tag6
01/03/2014,tag1
01/03/2014,tag4
01/03/2014,tag5
01/03/2014,tag6
01/03/2014,tag7
01/04/2014,tag1
01/04/2014,tag2
01/04/2014,tag3
01/04/2014,tag4
01/04/2014,tag6
01/04/2014,tag7
01/04/2014,tag9
01/05/2014,tag1
01/05/2014,tag3
01/05/2014,tag4
01/05/2014,tag5
01/05/2014,tag6
```

Here's the output I'm hoping for:

```
           tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4 tag5 tag6 tag7 tag9
01/01/2014    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0
01/02/2014    1    0    1    1    1    1    0    0
01/03/2014    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    0
01/04/2014    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    1
01/05/2014    1    0    1    1    1    1    0    0
```

Here's my working R code:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- read.csv("~/Desktop/tags.csv")
df$Value <- apply(df,1,function(row) 1)
tagMatrix <- dcast(df, Date~Tag, value.var="Value")
tagMatrix[is.na(tagMatrix)] <- 0
```

What is a better way to build a matrix like this from a two column data frame?

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply as `table` ! :)

```
> table(myDataFrame)
            Tag
Date         tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4 tag5 tag6 tag7 tag9
  01/01/2014    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0
  01/02/2014    1    0    1    1    1    1    0    0
  01/03/2014    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    0
  01/04/2014    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    1
  01/05/2014    1    0    1    1    1    1    0    0
```

Comment: wait...  "table-factorial" ?  :-)

Comment: Wow, talk about me finding a round about way to do something built in. I don't know why I couldn't get that working before. I think I was trying it on a three-column table instead of a two-column. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: Also, to get it back as a matrix data frame I used as.data.frame.matrix(myDataFrame).